# How to enable "Dashboards Objects" Feed Tracking in metadata?

Tags: marketingcloudapi

How can I set Dashboard objects feed tracking to true? Or is it possible to set the dashboard objecy feed tracking using package xml/ metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just like any other object - [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_feed_tracking.htm&type=5)

1. Setup --> Feature Settings --> Chatter --> Feed Tracking
2. Click on Dashboard
3. Enable Feed Tracking

[image]

---

In terms of package.xml/metadata - the info is stored in [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) under `enableFeeds`

> Indicates whether the object is enabled for feed tracking (true) or not (false).

But, Dashboard isn't a standard object you can retrieve nor edit its object metadata. The following error message will display if you try through sfdx - so **you'll have to do this in the UI.**

> Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Dashboard

Comment: Thank you so much Kris, just making sure if there's any possible way to deploy it through metadata. You answer everything, really big help. Appreciate